# supervisor not restarting the process

Tags: linux, bash, process, supervisord

I am using supervisor to monitor a process which is a small bash script to run a command.  Here is my supervisor process config file

```
 [program:ngrok_worker]
    command=/home/pi/scripts/remoteacess.sh
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
    stdout_logfile=/tmp/ngrok-worker.log
    stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/test.err.log
    redirect_stderr=true
```

when i see the log of supervisor in /var/log/supervisor i find

```
2017-05-08 19:56:23,089 INFO gave up: ngrok_worker entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2017-05-08 19:59:14,748 INFO spawned: 'ngrok_worker' with pid 16807
2017-05-08 19:59:14,879 INFO exited: ngrok_worker (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-05-08 19:59:15,901 INFO spawned: 'ngrok_worker' with pid 16817
2017-05-08 19:59:16,212 INFO exited: ngrok_worker (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-05-08 19:59:18,261 INFO spawned: 'ngrok_worker' with pid 16830
2017-05-08 19:59:18,731 INFO exited: ngrok_worker (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-05-08 19:59:21,789 INFO spawned: 'ngrok_worker' with pid 16882
2017-05-08 19:59:22,111 INFO exited: ngrok_worker (exit status 0; not expected)
2017-05-08 19:59:23,115 INFO gave up: ngrok_worker entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

I didn't find any typo error in the worker config file and i am not able to find out why supervisor is not able to restart the process if i kill it manually using `sudo kill <PID>`

Edit -1 : As per some suggestions here at this [link](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/212) 
`startsecs =0` but when i check the log, its like, this command is restarting the script again and again and that is why `ngrok` is creating new tunnel every 1 second which is not desirable.

Here is my bashscriot to run ngrok from bashscript

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo ngrok tcp 22 --config=/home/pi/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml  --log=stdout > /home/pi/ngrok.log &
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the ampersand (&) at the end of your script. That is sending the ngrok command to the background which supervisord recognizes as the service stopping. There's no need to run processes in the background with supervisord.

Also, why use a bash script to launch ngrok instead of launching it directly from the supervisord config file? Something like:

```
[program:ngrok_worker]
command=ngrok tcp 22 --config=/home/pi/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/ngrok-worker.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/test.err.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

Comment: I did the exact same thing, instead of starting it from the script, i run the command directly from supervisor config file and it worked perfectly fine.